# Copy a table column based on another table's condition

Tags: mysql

**I have two tables :**
table_one
table_two

**table_two has following columns :**
table_one_id
OldColumn
NewColumn

I need something like this :

```
$table_one_records = $table_one->find('all')->where(['some xyz condition']);
foreach($table_one_records as $key => $value){
    $table_two_record = $table_two->find('all')->where(['any condition goes here']);

    UPDATE table_two SET column1 = $table_two_record['column2'], column2 = null WHERE `id` = $table_two_record['id'];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.column1 = table1.column2,
    table1.column2 = NULL
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
  AND (table1 conditions)
  AND (table2 conditions)
```

And no iterations on PHP.